# Python script compiling with 2.7 over 3 even with shebang

Tags: python-3.x, unix, executable, raspbian, shebang

I'm trying to make a python script executable on a raspberry pi (unix), and it compiles with python2.7 even though I specify python3 in the shebang.

The shebang is: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

I have also run the command `alias python=python3`

To make executable I have run `chmod +x main.py` then I run `./main.py`

The problem is that I am trying to include sklearn modules, which are only correctly included with python3. The error I get is:

```
ImportError: No module named sklearn.multiclass
```

If I run the code with `python3 main.py` or `python main.py` it works, so I know the python3 alias works. Without the alias, `python main.py` gives the same error.

Anybody have any insight as to why this might be happening?

**Edit (question answers):**

This is not meant to be run on a virtual machine. I am trying to run with ./main.py

`which python3` returns /usr/bin/python3

`type python3` returns /usr/bin/python3

Comment: You only mention running it with `python main.py` and `python3 main.py`. Presumably you *are* trying to run it with `./main.py` ?

Comment: What’s the result of running `which python3`? What about `type python3`?

Comment: Is this supposed to be run in a virtual environment, or with the host python?